# How come a globally defined array that gets data pushed to it with in a callback function is empty in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I assign an empty array to the global variable `artistURLs`. I then push strings (the local variable `artistURL`) into the `artistURLs` array with in the Cheerio `.each()` iterator method.

```
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  url = 'http://www.primarytalent.com/',
  artistURLs = [];

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  if(err)
    throw err;
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('#rosterlists div li a').each(function(){
    var urlCap = this.attr('href').slice(1);
    var artistURL = url.concat(urlCap);
    artistURLs.push(artistURL);
  });
  console.log(artistURLs);
});
```

I know that `artistURL` is successfully being pushed into `artistURLs` because

`console.log(artistURLs);`

will display the populated array in my terminal. The problem is if I try running `console.log(artistURLs);` outside of the callback function in the global scope. For example

```
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  url = 'http://www.primarytalent.com/',
  artistURLs = [];

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  if(err)
    throw err;
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('#rosterlists div li a').each(function(){
    var urlCap = this.attr('href').slice(1);
    var artistURL = url.concat(urlCap);
    artistURLs.push(artistURL);
  });
});

console.log(artistURLs);
```

So you can see that I have moved `console.log(artistURLs);` outside of `request()`. For some reason trying to access `artistURLs` in the global scope returns me an empty array as if all the processing that happened with in `request()~ never even happened.

How come this is happening and how can ensure that all the urls that are being pushed into `artistURLs` remain in `artistURLs`?

Thanks

Comment: That's because the callback hasn't been run when you log the array in the global context. It's async

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request()` module is asynchronous, so `console.log()` is executing before the HTTP call completes when you use `console.log()`. For example, take this code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = 'http://www.primarytalent.com/';
var artistURLs = [];

request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  if (err)
    throw err;
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  $('#rosterlists div li a').each(function(){
    var urlCap = this.attr('href').slice(1);
    var artistURL = url.concat(urlCap);
    artistURLs.push(artistURL);
    console.log('push');
  });
});

console.log(artistURLs);
```

You will see this result:

```
[]
push
push
...
push
push
push
```

To prevent this from happening, only use the variable `artistURLs` inside of the HTTP request callback.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I guess my question should have been "How can I return  `artistURLs` out to the global scope?

Comment: The issue here is that `artistURLs` already does go to the global score, it's just that you're accessing it before any data has been pushed to that array. It is not possible to do what you're asking unless the HTTP request is synchronous.